# Why isn't ~/.profile sourced when I start the terminal app?

Tags: shell, terminal

I have created some busybox aliases in the `~/.profile` file, but when I open the terminal app, that script isn't sourced and the aliases aren't available. However, when I manually run `source ~/.profile`, it is run and then aliases are available. What should I do to source this script automatically each time the terminal app is started.

Comment: What term app are you using? Jackpal's Terminal Emulator does allow you to set what commands are executed at startup, so it could be a workaround.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Jackpal's terminal emulator! Where exactly should I place the commands that can be executed at startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackpal's Terminal Emulator has an option that allows you to set what commands are executed at startup. Go to Preferences - Initial command and put the `source` command there.

Extra tip: you can't execute more than one line of command from there, but if your command requires `su`, shortening it with `su -c` should work.

[image]